# Set breakpoint on a constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I am trying to set a breakpoint on a constructor for a class in an external assembly using `Debug`, `New Breakpoint`, `Break at function`.

I've tried using both `.ctor` and `ctor` as the function name but neither work

- `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult..ctor`
- `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.ctor`
- `System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.ViewResult`

If the class has multiple controllers then this will work;

- `System.Web.Mvc.HttpUnauthorizedResult.HttpUnauthorizedResult`

In some cases Visual Studio shows the constructor name as the class name such as with `HttpUnauthorizedResult`, but in other cases it shows the constructor name as `.ctor` such as with `System.Uri`.

---

[image: Breakpoints - System.Uri]

[image: Breakpoints]

Comment: I'm starting to think this does work, but is flaky, I just tried entering one breakpoint as `Foo.Foo` and VS changed it to `Foo..ctor` and it worked but if I enter `Foo..ctor` myself it does not work. In other cases when I've used `Foo.Foo` and VS has changed it to `Foo..ctor` the breakpoint has not worked.